# Implement Barcode in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, barcode

I want to Implement Barcode in MVC web App hosted on IIS, for Super Store. After 3 day research i found an example on google but that was not in MVC. Please tell me how can i Implement this code in MVC, so when i pass a string barcode image display in my view

```
public void CreateBarcode(string code)
        {
            var myBitmap = new Bitmap(500, 50);
            var g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
            var jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            g.Clear(Color.White);

            var strFormat = new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center };
            g.DrawString(code, new Font("Free 3 of 9", 50), Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, 0, 500, 50), strFormat);

            var myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
            var myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

            var myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);
            myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
            myBitmap.Save(@"E:\Barcode.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
        }

        public ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
        {

            var codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

            foreach (var codec in codecs)
            {
                if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
                {
                    return codec;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far and maybe somebody will then try to help.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic I m new in programming. and i m confused what should be the return type of void functions. At least tell me what should be return type of void functions. so i could store it some variable etc and then render it to my view.

Comment: void function do not return anything - that is why they are marked `void`

Comment: i know void return nothing. i was trying to ask what should be the data type instead of void???

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you know how to make a barcode and need to know how to get it from a controller to your page.  Here is a little code that may help you put it all together.

in your page

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Barcode", new { code = "*ABC123*" })" alt="" />
```

in your controller

```
public ActionResult Barcode(string code)
{
    var myBitmap = new Bitmap(500, 50);
    var g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);

    // the code that makes the barcode
    // the code that makes the barcode
    // the code that makes the barcode

    // Put the image into a stream to return
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    myBitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

    // Reset the stream position before returning it
    ms.Position = 0;
    return new FileStreamResult(ms, "image/png");
}
```

Comment: Thank u @MEC for your reply

Comment: but as i mentioned in my question i just copied the code from google. Could u please define little more???